# How to access Item text using: foreach(var Item in ListView.SelectedItems){}

Tags: c#, listview

I'm trying to get the value of each selected item in a list view.  Problem is that when I use Intellitext to find out what I can get out of "Item", my options are:

```
Equals<br/>
GetHashCode<br/>
GetType<br/>
ToString
```

When I use ToString, I get the following:

```
{Text = "ItemLabel"}
```

When all I want is:

ItemLabel

```
foreach(var Item in ListView.SelectedItems)
{
Item.ToString(); //{Text = "ItemLabel"}
}
```

How can I make it so that I can get the text that I want (without parsing the results from ToString).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ListViewItem` instead of `var`:

```
foreach(ListViewItem Item in ListView.SelectedItems)
{
    Item.Text; // "ItemLabel"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hum. If ListView.SelectedItems is an IEnumerable (and not an IEnumerable<T>), then var will infer the elements of the sequence as an Object. Specify the correct type instead.